# C# XPathSelectElement and xml with attribute xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Help

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xpath, xml-namespaces

I need to read an xml element which has attribute xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#".
XPathSelectElement is giving error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Here is the sample code.

```
var xml = "<root><tagA>Tag A</tagA><tagB>Tag B</tagB></root>";
XDocument xd = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var str = xd.XPathSelectElement("/root/tagB").ToString(SaveOptions.DisableFormatting);
Console.WriteLine(str);
```

The result of the above code is:

```
<tagB>Tag B</tagB>
```

If I put attribute,

```
var xml = "<root><tagA>Tag A</tagA><tagB xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#\">Tag B</tagB></root>";
```

I got error.

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Am I missing something here? Can anyone please help me out. (I know I can get by using other methods. I just want to know what I am missing here)

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can register the element's namespace in an [XmlNamespaceManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnamespacemanager.aspx):

```
XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
nsmgr.AddNamespace("ns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#");

var str = xd.XPathSelectElement("/root/ns:tagB", nsmgr)
            .ToString(SaveOptions.DisableFormatting);
Console.WriteLine(str);
```

Comment: I never remember to add the namespace the first time around.

Answer (score 2):

You should read some about XML. The `tagB` in the second example is in a different namespace. By default, you're querying the empty namespace, if you want to query a different one you need to use a namespace manager and assign the namespace to a prefix, then prefix the element name with this same prefix and it will work again.

```
XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xd.CreateNavigator().NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("xmldsig", "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#");
var str = xd.XPathSelectElement("/root/xmldsig:tagB", nsmgr).ToString(SaveOptions.DisableFormatting);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not just any attribute. For example try with

```
var xml = "<root><tagA>Tag A</tagA><tagB attr=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#\">Tag B</tagB></root>";
```

to see that it works.

The problem is that you change the namespace by using xmlns, so your XPath doesn't match anymore.